# Symfony 3.1.2 "The service 'profiler' has a dependency on a non-existent service 'debug.security.access.decision_manager'."

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony-3.1

After updating to the latest version of Symfony from 3.0.2 to 3.1.2 when I run the command.

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I now get the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>   The service "profiler" has a dependency on a non-existent service
>   "debug.security.access.decision_manager".

Does anyone know why this would happen, or what I could do to resolve this? I can add any additional information as needed. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had to do with the fact I was including debugging resources in the production environment. I was performing tests on the caching mechanisms and forgot to remove the inclusion from the config.yml and AppKernel.php files.

```
        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev','test','prod'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            //... Extensions From Base
            $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
    }
```

as such the AppKernel instantiation needed the debug parameter to be set to true.

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Otherwise it would cause the initial issue I asked this question to fix.